# Filtering query with BEGINSWITH of Realm database in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, realm

I am having issues with a query which includes BEGINSWITH (or CONTAINS for that matter). I am trying to follow the example as found in the Mongo Db documentation:

This query to find instances of the <Pantry> model is not filtering the way it should.

(all of this is in the viewModel)

This is the query:

```
val searchResults = realm
        .query<Pantry>("itemName BEGINSWITH $0", searchText.value)
        .find()
        .asFlow()
        .map { results ->
            results.list.toList()
        }
        .stateIn(
            viewModelScope,
            SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(),
            emptyList()
        )
```

`searchText` is a String with a search pattern input by the user to find instances of the Pantry model. This done by use of a TextField.

'realm' is defined like this: private val realm = `MyApp.realm`.

MyApp is :

```
class MyApp: Application() {

    companion object {
        lateinit var realm: Realm
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        realm = Realm.open(
            configuration = RealmConfiguration.create(
                schema = setOf(
                    Pantry::class,
                    Department::class,
                    Market::class,
                )
            )
        )
    }
}
```

I implemented this function to see what was happening; if the query was doing anything or not:

```
suspend fun checkSearchResults(){
        searchResults.collect { results ->
            if (results.isEmpty()) {
                Log.d("Search", "No search results found")
            } else {
                // Loop through or access items in results
                for (item in results) {
                    Log.d("Search", "Found item: ${item.itemName}")
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

This is the log as the user inputs characters:

```
The value of searchText: h
D  Found item: bananas
D  Found item: clorox
D  Found item: garbanzos
D  Found item: ham
D  Found item: laundry detergent, pods
D  Found item: milk
D  Found item: olives
D  Found item: pastries
D  Found item: salmon
D  Found item: water, sparkling
D  The value of searchText: ha
D  Found item: bananas
D  Found item: clorox
D  Found item: garbanzos
D  Found item: ham
D  Found item: laundry detergent, pods
D  Found item: milk
D  Found item: olives
D  Found item: pastries
D  Found item: salmon
D  Found item: water, sparkling
D  The value of searchText: ham
D  Found item: bananas
D  Found item: clorox
D  Found item: garbanzos
D  Found item: ham
D  Found item: laundry detergent, pods
D  Found item: milk
D  Found item: olives
D  Found item: pastries
D  Found item: salmon
D  Found item: water, sparkling
```

which is the entire database.

So, from the log its evident that the query is ignoring the filter and all instances are included.

Can anyone point out where I am failing? I think I'm following the documentation pretty closely.

UPDATE:
if I use a query like this:
`.query<Pantry>("itemName = $0", searchText.value)` and using a known `itemName`, the result is an empty list.

UPDATE 2:
`searchResults` does not update. My understanding was that because it's a `StateFlow` it would update each time the conditions change (`searchtext.value`), but its not happening.

Comment: Can you try something? Change your query to `val results: RealmResults<Pantry> = realm.query<Pantry>("itemName BEGINSWITH $0", searchText.value)` and then `val x = results.find()` and then output the value of x. Does it still output the entire database?

Comment: @Jay, I will try it and report the finding.

Comment: @Jay, I did as you suggested, but the results don't change. Still get all the database objects. Had to change the type of results to `RealmQuery` because of type mismatch, but **x** ended up being of `RealmResults` type. Any other suggestions?  Thank you for pitching in.

Comment: Probably won't make a difference but what if you hard code an `"h"` in the place of `searchText.value`?

Comment: I did. I've done so many things. I've been working on this for over a week. I have something else up my sleeve. I'll let you know tomorrow. @Jay

Answer (score 0):

This was the issue: the value of `searchResults` was not **updating**, therefore even though the `textField` was issuing characters to the `searchText variable`, **nothing** was happening.

The solution: force an update on the variable `searchResults`. This was accomplished by enclosing the code for `searchResults` in a function and calling the function from the `onValueChange` in the `textField`.

Complications: My understanding is that just because a function is called, doesn't necessarily  generate an update on a `StateFlow` entity, so by enclosing it in a **.collect** can make that happen. Complications between `viewModel` and the `Composable` and the use of **var** and **val** in the declaration of `variables`.

So to solve for said complications, I declared the following:

```
private val _searchResults = MutableStateFlow<List<Pantry>>(emptyList())
var searchResults: StateFlow<List<Pantry>> = _searchResults.asStateFlow()
```

1 for use in the viewModel and the other for the Composable.

and this is the function:

```
suspend fun fetchSearchResults(searchTerm: String) {
    realm.query<Pantry>("itemName CONTAINS $0", searchTerm)
        .find()
        .asFlow()
        .map { results -> results.list.toList() }
        .collect { filteredList ->
            _searchResults.value = filteredList 
        }
}
```

it needs to be in a `suspend function`, due to the `.collect`.

So the function is called from the `textField`:

```
TextField(
        value = searchText,
        onValueChange = { viewModel.changeText(it)
                  scope.launch {
                      viewModel.fetchSearchResults(it)
                  }
                               },
```

It works pretty well. Tested it **CONTAINS** and with **BEGINSWITH** and both work.